# Can we create an excel table from data columns which are not in sequence of columns

Tags: excel, excel-tables

I've data which is similar to below data.

```
rollno  name    branch  college
---------------------------------
1       a       b1      c1
2       b       b2      c2
3       c       b3      c3
4       d       b4      c4
5       e       b5      c5
```

I want to create table for this data by skipping branch column.

```
rollno  name    college
-------------------------
1       a       c1
2       b       c2
3       c       c3
4       d       c4
5       e       c5
```

Is their anyway we can to create the table by selecting the specific columns of the given data.

Comment: Use Power Query - load in all the data, then just remove the column(s) you don't want.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

Using the power query we can do it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).